# MacBook Pro Internal Hard Drive dead?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, startup

Not too long ago, I tried to update my MacBook Pro to the newest OS (Mojave).
I downloaded the updater etc. and started updating my software. I didn't mind, so I just let it update for itself. I came back some hours after, to a black screen, and nothing responding. The computer didn't respond to any clicks neither to the keyboard, or lastly the display/screen getting closed.

I tried to shut down the computer by holding the power button. I then proceed to try to open it again and it shows a blinking folder with a question mark, which I found out, means it can't find a bootable drive.

I tried to open it in recovery mode, and from there download the OS, but every time I agreed to the terms and conditions etc. it sent me to the page, where I had to pick which hard drive the OS would be downloaded on, but I had nothing to choose. Nothing was there.

I also tried to go to disk utility, and I can't see my hard drive on the left side.

Does this mean my internal hard drive is dead? What does this mean, and what can I do?

Thank you for reading

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) This simply means your Mac is not able to access the hard drive. Reconnecting the hard drive should work. This happened with me a while ago, and shaking the MacBook a bit did the trick for me.

Comment: For dyi, try ifixit.com if you want to try a self repair.  You can buy  a external drive and install and boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Not withstanding Nimesh's comment and presuming that method does not work...

Installing Mojave was undoubtedly not the cause of this issue, more like just coincidental. That said it is likely that something has happened to the HD (or SSD) in your MacBook pro.

It could be a loose connection, it could be a damaged/dead drive. heck it could be a number of things. But the one thing they have in common is that it is likely that the MacBook will need to be opened and serviced by a tech competent in doing said work.

If it is within warranty take it to your nearest Apple store. If there is not an Apple store nearby, call Apple tech support.

If it is out of warranty you can still take it to Apple but they will charge you for the fix. Possibly more than an independent Apple dealer might. But that would be your choice and based on your local experience with Apple stores, dealers and the repair jobs they are experienced with.